# When retrieving a text file using jQuery, I get 404 not found, but the file should be there for sure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

The directory has just the HTML file, the JavaScript file, and the file called `words.txt` holding a ton of words. On my computer, the code worked just fine - I ran a simple HTTP server with Python and jQuery was able to load the list perfectly. When I uploaded all the files to 000webhost to test, the `words.txt` wouldn't load. The Firefox error console says it's giving a 404 Not Found, even though I'm sure the file is there. I'm getting the file like this:

```
var wordList = [];
$.get('words.txt', function(data){
    wordList = data.split('\r\n');
});
```

On my computer with an HTTP Server, it'll work fine, but on the web host, it won't. Does it have something to do with this HTACCESS file? Should I be calling the file path for `words.txt` differently? It's in the same directory setup as it was on my PC, so I don't see why it wouldn't work on the host...

edit: I've also tried looking at chmod permissions. Even when Read, Write, and Execute are checked for everything possible, it won't get the file.

Comment: Troubleshoot: First check the file permissions on the server for read access. Next: try '/words.txt' for the url (add '/').

Comment: Copy the `url` from 404 error shown in browser console, paste it in browser URL bar and see if the file is there.

Comment: File permissions: I checked Read, Write and Execute just to test - still won't return file. Tried adding '/'. File won't return. This might be interesting - when I try to visit the file itself through the web browser (http://example.com/words.txt), it just shows me a blank page. When I view source of the page, it's also blank. The file is definitely in the web host's directory, right next to script.js and index.html...

Comment: try changing the extension to html or js

Comment: Worked! Had to change `data.split('\r\n')` to `data.split('\n')` as well. These pesky newlines. Thanks for the file extension tip, though.

Comment: Add it as an answer so I can accept it?